# Extract specific information from text

Tags: php, regex, text

I have a string:

> He was feeling a bit chilly at home and asked the assistant “What’s
>   the temperature inside?” He figured that the system would figure out
>   the temperature from his Nest thermostat and report that back to
>   him. Instead, the Google Assistant went and fetched the weather report
>   for, a resort town in Turkey.

This is my function to get all uppercase words:

```
public static function getUpperCase($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

My output is:

```
1: "He"
2: "What"
3: "He"
4: "Nest"
5: "Instead"
6: "Google"
7: "Assistant"
8: "Turkey"
```

How can I get n-gramms:

```
1: "He"
2: "What"
3: "He"
4: "Nest"
5: "Instead"
6: "Google Assistant"
7: "Turkey"
```

So I want to group words together if no any words between uppercased words in sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your regex to search for whitespace followed by a capitalized word as many times as it greedily can after your initial capitalized word match.

```
public static function getUpperCase($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*\b/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with that sentence: That could help Cisco Spark Assistant and the Cisco Spark chat app room hold their own against popular services like Slack, Microsoft Teams, and Facebook’s Workplace Chat, which came to desktop computers this week.

Comment: 1: "Cisco Spark Assistant   Cisco Spark" [bug]
2: "Slack"
3: "Microsoft Teams"
4: "Facebook" [bug]
5: "Workplace Chat" [bug]

Comment: Do you know where is a problem in first element of output array?

Comment: Hmm. When I run a test with that input and using the regex from my answer, I get: `[0] => That [1] => Cisco Spark Assistant [2] => Cisco Spark [3] => Slack [4] => Microsoft Teams [5] => Facebook [6] => Workplace Chat` which seems correct to me. I did update my answer a few times as I was debugging it. Can you try to copy/paste my answer into your code again and test? Maybe you didn't get the final version.

Comment: Actually, I see now that you're expecting `Facebook’s Workplace Chat` to be one match. If apostrophes are valid, it would contradict your initial example which would include `What’s` instead of `What` as you initially wanted. So which is correct for your use case?

Comment: Not only that, it seems your sample text includes a "smart quote" instead of a regular single quote. This complicates the matter further. If you would like an expression that works for that example, this one will work: `preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z’\']*(\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z’\']*)*\b/', $str, $matches);` Notice I've included both a "smart quote" and an escaped regular apostrophe in the character class. Those are 2 different characters!

Comment: It works correct with Facebook in first regex. But I don't understand this output: [1]: Cisco Spark Assistant   Cisco Spark

Comment: I cannot duplicate your result. As I've stated above; when I try with the input in your comment `Cisco Spark Assistant` and `Cisco Spark` are separated into 2 different tokens. If you're still having issues, please post your exact input and code in a new question. There are too many comments on this answer. Thanks!